# I want a Result set from a column using In query but there is some error conversion is failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @val varchar(50)='247,254'
Select * from fn_SplitString(@val,'') 
Select UserInfo.UserId from UserInfo where UserId in (Select * from fn_SplitString(@val,''))


fn_SplitString

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString]
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
```

> Error:Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '247,254' to
>   data type int.

please help me out

Comment: Your number has a comma. You need to deal with that first

Comment: You are passing incorrect deliminator to the function, it should be ',' instead of ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 you can use string_split as below:

```
Declare @val varchar(50)='247,254'
Select * from fn_SplitString(@val,'') 
Select UserInfo.UserId from UserInfo where UserId in (Select value from string_split(@val, ','))
```

Else for other versions you can create custom function...

Answer (score 0):

First, just run your function directly on data, so you can see how it works.  This is called testing.

So, if you are running:

```
Select * from fn_SplitString(@val, '') ;
```

Then *look* at the results.  You may figure out that you have provided no separator.

So try:

```
Select * from fn_SplitString(@val, ',') ;
```

This will probably fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace '' with ',' and your code will work.
On top of that, if you use SQL‌ server 2016 you can use the native function String_Split:

```
 SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('247,254',',') AS SS
```

this way you do not need any user defined function for the task.